# Is there a webserver that can be built for Windows Mobile 6 that dynamically generates pages?

Tags: windows-mobile, webserver, opera, tiddlywiki

Okay,

Now admittedly this sounds like a silly question;

But, I actually have a need for this.  I use tiddlywiki alot, and it'd be really, really cool if I could save changes to a tiddlywiki in some mobile browser.

But it seems that with all the mobile browsers that I've tried, changes I make to my tiddlywiki cannot be saved to an SD Card;

However it seems that although some mobile browsers are quite capable of loading and saving changes that are hosted on a webserver (I've actually tried this on my blog on Tiddlyspot.com with opera-mini and successfully saved the changes.)

Now, if I could just host a webserver that runs on my Windows Mobile device, and that webserver could be capable of running a simple dynamic page generation language and some-how writing and reading from a txt file or database of some sort, I could access/modifiy my tiddlywiki's without having to pay to host them somewhere (even if I have to write the backend myself it'd be worth it!)

Here are a few mobile-webservers I've found:

- [Tiny Java Webserver and Container](http://tjws.sourceforge.net/)

  - Only problem with this one is that I don't think my WM6 device can run more than on JVM at the same time (thus that knocks out most of the browsers I'd use to access it since..*ahem* they're mostly written in Java...)
- [Mobile Web Server](http://www.sphinx-soft.com/MWS/index.html)

  - Seems good, but there doesn't seem to be any way to run a backend (just seems to serve up pages).

Comment: "you could probably do that with the existing server-side implementations (e.g. @TiddlyWeb's CherryPy server)"
- @Tiddlywiki on Twitter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Mobile has a built in basic web server (HTTPD) that I think can support ASP and has support for ISAPI filters (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa926719.aspx)). If ASP ain't your thing you could probably get some light weight scripting languages to run under CE, still a daunting task and you will still need to write the wiki software.

Why not use one of the many free hosted wikis? (see a comparison [here](http://www.wikimatrix.org/))

Comment: @nic I wouldn't want to use a hosted wiki because usually its content from a copy written book that I'm transcribing/taking notes on in the wiki (hence I can't post the content of the wiki online).